# Convex Functions are Locally Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification, proof-explanation, convex-analysis

I was introduced in the class the following lemma:

If $\phi: E \to (-\infty, \infty]$ is convex and upper bounded on a neighborhood of a point $x \in D(\phi)$(i.e. the domain of $\phi$), then $\phi$ is continuous at $x$.

The proof goes as follow:

> **Translate and dilate to get $\phi(0) = 0$ and $\phi(x)$ < 1 on $B(0, r)$.** Fix $\epsilon > 0$ and $\frac{x}{\epsilon} \in B(0, r)$. Then
> $$
> \begin{align}
> 0 = \phi(0) &= \phi(\frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} x + (1 - \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon}(-\frac{x}{\epsilon})) \\
> 0 &\leq \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \phi(x) + \frac{\epsilon}{1 + \epsilon} \phi(-\frac{x}{\epsilon}) \\
> &\leq \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \phi(x) + \frac{\epsilon}{1 + \epsilon} \cdot 1
> \end{align}
> $$
> That is, we have $\phi(x) \geq -\epsilon$ on $B(0, \epsilon r)$. On the other hand, we have
> $$
> \phi(x) = \phi((1 - \epsilon) \cdot 0 + \epsilon \frac{x}{\epsilon}) \leq (1 - \epsilon) \phi(0) + \epsilon \phi(\frac{x}{\epsilon}) \leq 0 + \epsilon \cdot 1 = \epsilon.
> $$
> This shows $|\phi(x)| < \epsilon$ on $B(0, \epsilon r)$.

My **first question** is the bolded part of the proof: I wonder why can we do this? Is it always true that we can do this?

My **second question** is about a comment that follows the proof:

> In the proof, $\phi(x) \approx \phi(x) - \phi(0)$ and we showed that $\phi$ is locally lipschitz on $Int(D(\phi))$:
> $$|\phi(x) - \phi(0)| < \epsilon$$
> on $B(0, r\epsilon)$ is what we have showed and so if we let $\| x \| = r\epsilon$, then
> $$
> \frac{\phi(x) - \phi(0)}{\| x - 0 \|} \leq \frac{\epsilon}{\| x \|} \leq \frac{1}{r}.
> $$

My question is, why does this show $\phi$ locally Lipschitz? How does this part naturally fit into the proof given in the lemma?

Comment: what is $E$? Is it a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n?$

Comment: @Mahdi It is an arbitrary Banach space.

Comment: Regarding first part, this is part of the proof. Given convex $\phi$, $a \phi + c$ is also convex for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and any $a > 0$. So they're just saying "multiply by the appropriate $a$ and add by appropriate $c$ so that the remaining calculations are as simple as possible."